# Trouble with my chrome extension. jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

This is my first time making a Chrome extension and I think my javascript/jQuery is not loading.

These are my scripts from different files.

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

---

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!--<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.0/amcharts.js'></script>-->

<script src="more.js"></script>
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

And this is my Github [repo](https://github.com/furball514/TheMoneroPug-v.1.0).

Also I want to remote access jQuery I don't want to host it myself.

I'm using a bunch of APIs like reddit,stackexchange,cryptonator,bitcointalk(unofficial).
Perhaps I have to declare these or jQuery in the manifest.json?

This is my manifest.json file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TheMoneroPug",
  "short_name":"MoneroPug",
  "author": "Karthik",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "version_name": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Chrome extension for viewing Monero price(for traders)",
  "icons": {"128":"main/128.png"},
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
   "16": "main/16.png",
   "48": "main/48.png"
  },
    "default_title": "TheMoneroPug",
   "default_popup": "main/popup.html"
  },
  "options_ui": {
   "page": "setting/options.html",
  "chrome_style": true
  },
 "background": {
  "scripts": [
  "main/popup.js",
  "more/more.js",
  "setting/options.js"
  ]
 },
 "permissions": [
 "storage"
  ]
 }
```

I do not have any background.html files the browser action is popup.
The error is with jQuery shows that $ is not defined and the error

> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Rightclick your popup/options, then `Inspect`: you'll see an error. The easiest solution is to include jquery locally with the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the jQuery CDN you're using to the sites allowed by the content security policy in the manifest.

By default only scripts included in the extension are allowed, and as the whole extension is downloaded on install there's no advantage in using a CDN.